# Firebase Invite SMS not clickable

Tags: android, firebase-invites

**NOTE: Firebase Invites is deprecated now & it is recommended to use Dynamic links - https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/deprecation**

This post is not valid anymore.

I tried to implement Firebase Invite following the docs : https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android

The mail invite seem to work well, but the sms is not clickable and after copying the link and pasting it in browser, it is not opening playstore automatically!

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Deep Link

`.setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))`

Just put in any value, or use the Google Play link to your app.